# Handling Concurrent xmlhttprequests

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

In a single function, I want to download three resources using xmlhttprequests; when they are loaded, I want to call a function using the responses from the aforementioned requests. However when I try to call the function the required aforementioned responses are undefined.

```
function(){
var File=null
var Meta=null
var Engine=null
var xhrFile = new XMLHttpRequest()
var xhrMeta = new XMLHttpRequest();
var xhrEngine = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrFile.open('GET','/archive/file.txt',true)
xhrMeta.open('GET','/template/file.js',true)
xhrEngine.open('GET','/javascript/app/hemp/engine.js',true)
xhrFile.responseType='arraybuffer';
xhrMeta.responseType='text';
xhrEngine.responseType='text';
xhrFile.onload = function(){File=xhrFile.response}
xhrMeta.onload = function(){File=eval(xhrMeta.response)}    
xhrEngine.onload = function(){Engine=eval(xhrEngine.response)}
xhrFile.send();
xhrMeta.send();
xhrEngine.send();
var DDM=Engine({'file':File,'meta':Meta}) 
return DDM
};
```

The code does not work and needs some retrofit!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for asking programming questions, not just asking people to *fix* your code for you.

Comment: Maybe you have to retrofit your semiotics.. they look too tight

Comment: Please add details on "code does not work". Also try to make your code more consistent (variable names capitalization, use of semicolons) - current sample shows lack of effort on your side which is not exactly welcome here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last part:
    var DDM=Engine({'file':File,'meta':Meta}) 
    return DDM

Will always yield undefined because at that point, *File* and *Meta* may not have been assigned anything yet since the XMLHttpRequests may not have returned yet. In other words, their .onload() functions aren't called yet, thus File/Meta would not be defined yet.

What you want to do is inside the onload(), check for File and/or Meta to see if they're defined (aka their XMLHttpRequests have successfully returned). If they are, then you can call Engine({'file':File, 'meta': Meta}) because at that point they exist.

Comment: Yes, I did included a trigger to call the function based on the status of the three variables in every onload listener.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it... It wasn't hard ... just a little bit of imagination

```
var solve = function(File,Meta,Engine){
    var DDM=Engine({'file':File,'meta':Meta});
    return DDM;
};


//code added to the onload listeners 
xhrFile.onload = function(){
    File=xhrFile.response;
    if (File && Meta && Engine){
        return solve(File,Meta,Engine);
    }
};
xhrMeta.onload = function(){
    Meta=eval(xhrMeta.response);
    if (File && Meta && Engine){
        return solve(File,Meta,Engine);
    }
};
xhrEngine.onload = function(){
    Engine=eval(xhrEngine.response);
    if (File && Meta && Engine){
        return solve(File,Meta,Engine);
    }
};
```